# SVN: Update whole project after having been working with one folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using TortoiseSVN.

I had previously been working with only one subfolder of a repository folder. So I was only updating/commiting on that subfolder and never downloaded the other ones.

I would now want to retrieve the whole main folder. So I did a checkout on the parent directory but obviously when I want to update on the parent directory it tells me that a 
 `versioned directory of the same name already exists`

How can I indicate to SVN that this directory is already downloaded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest answer, assuming everything is checked in, is to simply blow away the directory and let Subversion check it out again.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the folder and check it out with the parent folder again.

If you made local changes that you want to keep, create a patch for it. There is a description of how to do that with plain svn [here](http://ariejan.net/2007/07/03/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-subversion/).
With Tortoise, you only need to choose "Create Patch" and "Apply Patch".
In either case, update your working copy before creating the patch!

Comment: If you want to keep the changes, just rename the directory and restore it after checkout.

Comment: @Tgr And mess around with the .svn folders and overwriting changes that others made in the meantime?